# Button overlay right middle of card image

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I'm making a blog using NextJS and TailwindCSS. I've made a card, that the button overlays the card image right in the middle. But the button stays a little higher. Image: [image]

And here is the code:

```
<div className="relative max-w-5xl mx-auto px-2 grid grid-cols-3">
        <div className="relative overflow-hidden flex items-center justify-center flex-col">
          <Image
            src={
              "https://static.wixstatic.com/media/5bfb6f_9f2519d5fc2d41f990a10dd92eb8658d.jpg/v1/fill/w_393,h_325,al_c,q_80,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01,enc_auto/5bfb6f_9f2519d5fc2d41f990a10dd92eb8658d.jpg"
            }
            width={314}
            height={314}
            alt="Image"
            className="object-cover"
          />
          <div className="absolute w-full h-full top-0 bottom-0 left-0 right-0">
            <button className="text-xl px-4 py-2 rounded text-blue-600 bg-white absolute bottom-1/2 left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2">Travel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I've tried using absolute and relative positions. I've also tried using flexbox. But nothing worked. I'm expecting that the button will overlay on the image right on the center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but I think the easiest fix here is, instead of using absolute for the button, just add `flex items-center justify-center` to the parent class of button like this:

```html
<div class="relative max-w-5xl mx-auto px-2 grid grid-cols-3">
  <div class="relative overflow-hidden flex items-center justify-center flex-col">
    <img
      src="https://via.placeholder.com/314x314"
      width="314"
      height="314"
      alt="Image"
      class="object-cover"
    />
    <div class="absolute w-full h-full top-0 bottom-0 left-0 right-0 flex items-center justify-center">
      <button class="text-xl px-4 py-2 rounded text-blue-600 bg-white">Travel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```